# Get Next Month In PHP

Tags: php, calendar

I have a php calendar that works fine for THIS month but I'd like to create another 2 scripts that show the next 2 months. I want to use the same format as the one I already have but I'm not completely sure on what I need to change to get it to display the dates of months 2 & 3.  Here is my code for Month 1:

```
<?php 
    $currDay        =    date("j");
    $today          =    date("d"); // Current day
    $month          =    date("m"); // Current month
    $displaymonth   =    date("F");
    $year           =    date("Y"); // Current year

    // Days in current month
    $days           =    cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);
?>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$firstMonth= date('F', strtotime('+1 months'));
$secondMonth= date('F', strtotime('+1 months'));
```

strtotime returns timestamp for next and date('F') will convert it to your desired format.

Comment: '+1 months' in second one also?

Comment: That's the one I needed

Comment: Also seem to fail for "2021-01-31". It returns 3rd of March.

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
$datetime = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d')); // Date object for current date
$datetime->modify('next month'); // Modifying object to next month date
$next_month_num = $datetime->format('m'); // In Numeric 01,02...
$next_month_str = $datetime->format('M'); // In String Jan,Feb
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the year based on the next month?

Comment: `$datetime->format('Y'); // You can use any date format here`

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way of simply updating the code I already have using strtotime, etc as the code above does not display any dates for the next month - I'd also like to be able to use this for 2 months ahead

Comment: Dont like that. This returns wrong date if you add a month to 31. January (returns 3rd of March but expected to return 28th of February):

$d = new DateTime("2021-01-31");
$d->modify('next month');
echo $d->format("Y-m-d");

Comment: I also had the problem that volker had where it was skipping over months

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach(range(0,2) as $monthoffset)
{  $datetime = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d')); // Date object for current date
    $datetime->modify('+'.$monthoffset.' month'); // Modifying object
    $timestamp=$datetime->getTimestamp(); // Getting the resulting timestamp, required by date function

    // Setting the constants your calendar 
    $currDay        =    date("j",$timestamp);
    $today          =    date("d",$timestamp); // Day
    $month          =    date("m",$timestamp); // Month
    $displaymonth   =    date("F",$timestamp);
    $year           =    date("Y",$timestamp); // Year

    // Days current month
    $days           =    cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);

    // Put the code which displays your calendar from here. It will be executed three times
    echo($displaymonth." ".$year."<br />");
}
?>
```

Will output :

```
December 2013
January 2014
February 2014
```

Assuming that we are in december, 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The most compact answer I can think of to this problem, which is surprising considering it's so common and yet it has problems to use the +1 month type answers, which I see skipping over 28 day februarys etc, etc. Is as follows:

```
// starting values
$month = 1;
$year = 2020;

// Increment the month to the next one
$month = $month + 1;

// If the month is greater than 12, add a year
$year = $month > 12 ? $year+1 : $year;

// Afterwards use the modulo of the month against 12
// but if it equals 0, use ?: to override that to 1
$month = $month % 12 ?: 1;
```

So obviously this can be cut down to three uncommented lines. So its really short and to the point. I've tried it with numerous iterations and starting places and I've not found a problem with it yet.

I wrote a small program which tests it:

```
<?php

$year=2020;
$month=0;
$a = 0;

do{
    $month = $month + 1;
    $year = $month > 12 ? $year+1 : $year;
    $month = $month % 12 ?: 12;
    $f="$year-$month";
    $d = new \DateTime(date($f));
    print("$f == Y:".$d->format('Y').", m:".$d->format('F')."\n");

    $a++;
}while($a<64);
```

and it outputs this:

```
2020-1 == Y:2020, m:January
2020-2 == Y:2020, m:February
2020-3 == Y:2020, m:March
2020-4 == Y:2020, m:April
2020-5 == Y:2020, m:May
2020-6 == Y:2020, m:June
2020-7 == Y:2020, m:July
2020-8 == Y:2020, m:August
2020-9 == Y:2020, m:September
2020-10 == Y:2020, m:October
2020-11 == Y:2020, m:November
2020-12 == Y:2020, m:December
2021-1 == Y:2021, m:January
2021-2 == Y:2021, m:February
2021-3 == Y:2021, m:March
2021-4 == Y:2021, m:April
2021-5 == Y:2021, m:May
2021-6 == Y:2021, m:June
2021-7 == Y:2021, m:July
2021-8 == Y:2021, m:August
2021-9 == Y:2021, m:September
2021-10 == Y:2021, m:October
2021-11 == Y:2021, m:November
2021-12 == Y:2021, m:December
2022-1 == Y:2022, m:January
2022-2 == Y:2022, m:February
2022-3 == Y:2022, m:March
2022-4 == Y:2022, m:April
2022-5 == Y:2022, m:May
2022-6 == Y:2022, m:June
2022-7 == Y:2022, m:July
2022-8 == Y:2022, m:August
2022-9 == Y:2022, m:September
2022-10 == Y:2022, m:October
2022-11 == Y:2022, m:November
2022-12 == Y:2022, m:December
2023-1 == Y:2023, m:January
2023-2 == Y:2023, m:February
```